# How can one atomically UPDATE a relation, receiving a set of tuples joined with another relation as a result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following transaction:

```
BEGIN;

    SELECT t1.a, t2.b
      FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.c = t2.c)
     WHERE t1.cond;

     UPDATE table1
        SET d = 'Value'
      WHERE cond;

COMMIT;
```

As I am updating the same table using the same condition, I could do the following, discarding the need for the transaction:

```
   UPDATE table1
      SET d = 'Value'
    WHERE cond
RETURNING a;
```

This way, I would lose the `b` attribute from `table2`. I have attempted the following:

```
    SELECT t1.a, t2.b
      FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.c = t2.c)
     WHERE t1.a IN (
                       UPDATE table1
                          SET d = 'Value'
                        WHERE cond
                    RETURNING a
                   );
```

And:

```
    SELECT t1.a, t2.b
      FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.c = t2.c)
INNER JOIN (
               UPDATE table1
                  SET d = 'Value'
                WHERE cond
            RETURNING a
           ) u ON (t1.a = u.a);
```

Both of these produced syntax errors (the first complained about the `UPDATE`, the second about the `SET`).

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your goal here? What do you want to return after executing the UPDATE?

Comment: My goal is to obtain the t1.a and t2.b attributes from the updated rows in t1 joined with t2. As demonstrated, obtaining t1.a is simple, and I could easily make a SELECT for every row, joining its a with t2, but the number of updated rows can be very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update table1 as t1
  SET d = 'Value'
from table2 as t2
where t1.c = t2.c
  and ...condition...
returning t1.a, t2.b;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly! Would the same syntax work for joining multiple relations, not just t2?

Comment: @Thanix: Works for any number of relations.